# SQL Like Statement is showing all results

Tags: mysql

I have used LIKE statements before and have been spending ages rewriting the statement and not sure what I have done wrong. When the query is ran, it displays all records in the database when it should be showing a more narrow list.

The reason for using a LIKE statement is to make my advanced search facility more efficient by allow part of a "property name".

**SQL Statement:**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    properties
WHERE
    PropertyName LIKE '%$PropertyName%'
    OR PropertyLocation LIKE '%$PropertyLocation%'
    OR PropertyType LIKE '%$PropertyType%'
    OR PropertyBeds='$PropertyBeds'
    OR PropertyRate >= '$PropertyRate1'
    AND PropertyRate <= '$PropertyRate2'
```

**Please note:** The statement does work without using like and wildcards.

Comment: Edit your question and tag with the database you are using.  Also, show the values of the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditions are:

```
WHERE PropertyName LIKE '%$PropertyName%' or
      PropertyLocation LIKE '%$PropertyLocation%' or
      PropertyType LIKE '%$PropertyType%' or
      PropertyBeds = '$PropertyBeds' or
      PropertyRate >= '$PropertyRate1' and PropertyRate <= '$PropertyRate2'
```

If `PropertyName`, `PropertyLocation`, or `PropertyType` are empty strings, then you will return all the rows.  That is my first guess on what is happening.

Perhaps you want `AND` as a connector rather than `OR`.

Comment: Thank you, I have just tested it and that is whats happening. I want the user to be allowed to search for what they want from the advanced search consequently, I want the statement to allow for empty strings.  Do you have any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: @JoeCobain . . . You should ask *another* question with a more detailed explanation of what you want to happen when different variables are set.